How to connect to exchange online powershell from IBM SOAR?
Does anyone know how I can connect to Exchange Online PowerShell from IBM SOAR?
I have been reading Microsoft documentation to check the ways I can connect, but they are all commands through powershell, and I would like to know if this is the only way, where I have to connect via ssh and execute the commands, or if there is another way.
